# command line string switching

Tags: string, command-line, piping

I have a command that generates two possible outputs ('dis' and 'en'). I want to pipe it into another command that switches one to the other ('dis' -> 'en', 'en' -> 'dis'). What's the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but should work:

```
result=`myCommand`
if [ $result = 'dis' ]; then
    output='en'
elif [ $result = 'en' ]; then
    output='dis'
fi
```